# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make a mute command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a mute command for my bot, here's my code:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Muted')
  await client.add_roles(member, role)
  embed=discord.Embed(title="User Muted!", description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=random.choice(colors))
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When triggered, it gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'`. I also tried using `ctx.add_roles`, but that won't work either.

I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the error, [`discord.ext.commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) object has no attribute `add_roles`, but [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) has.

```py
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Muted')
  await member.add_roles(role)
  embed=discord.Embed(title="User Muted!", description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=random.choice(colors))
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

## Reference

- [`discord.Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)

Comment: Hmm, it now gives me this: `404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role`

Comment: Are you sure that you have a role named `Muted`?

Comment: Yeah I'm positive

Comment: What is your discord.py version?

Comment: Wait nvm I got it to work, thanks a bunch! But I have one more question- is there a way to specify the amount of *time* that I want them to be muted for?

Comment: It's more complicated. You'll need a database, you have to save the times. Then, you need a loop to check if it's time to unmute users.

Comment: Mkay I'll look into that. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you need to use `member.add_roles()` but you should also get the role by it's ID with [`ctx.guild.get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get%20role#discord.Guild.get_role) because right now you are searching for the role in the roles the Member already has.
You can get this ID by enabling Developer Mode in User Settings > Appearance, then right click the Mute role in the server roles > copy ID.

```py
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  role = ctx.guild.get_role(<mute_role_id>)
  await member.add_roles(role)
  embed=discord.Embed(title="User Muted!", description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=random.choice(colors))
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Hmm, it now gives me this: `404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role`. I know I copied the ID correctly

Comment: Which version of discord.py are you using `pip show discord.py`?

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of Discord.py, `add_roles` is a method on member objects, not the bot object. This is why you're seeing "'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'".

You need to use `await member.add_roles(role)`